# Modifiable array-of-structures to represent devices

Tags: java

I'm really only a tinkerer in Java, but for work I need to write in Java for a while. Most of my experience is in C / C++ / JavaScript.

Anyway, the program needs arrays of structured data. Then, based on runtime criteria, the program needs to be able to add to or modify part of the data. Later the program will use the modified data to accomplish its objectives.

Today I spent a while looking for ways to do this in Java. I was able to achieve the goal using `ArrayList`s of class objects.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;  

class BusConfig extends Object {
    public int bus;
    public int gpio;
    public ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String> ( );
    public BusConfig( int newBus, int newGPIO, String[] newDevices ) {
        this.bus = newBus;
        this.gpio = newGPIO;
        this.devices = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( newDevices ) );
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format( "{ bus %d, gpio %d, devices %s }", this.bus, this.gpio, this.devices.toString() );
    }
}

class ConfigData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean IS_EXTENDED = false;
        ArrayList<BusConfig> basicConfig = new ArrayList<BusConfig>();
        basicConfig.add( new BusConfig( 0, -1, new String[] { "0xa6" } ) );
        basicConfig.add( new BusConfig( 1, 35, new String[] { "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4" } ) );
        basicConfig.add( new BusConfig( 2, 38, new String[] { "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4" } ) );
        ArrayList<BusConfig> extendConfig = new ArrayList<BusConfig>();
        extendConfig.add( new BusConfig( 8, -1, new String[] { "0xe8" } ) );
        ArrayList<String> extendBus0Device = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( new String[] { "0xa8" } ) );
        if( IS_EXTENDED ) {
            basicConfig.get(0).devices.addAll(extendBus0Device);
            basicConfig.addAll(extendConfig);
        }
        System.out.println( basicConfig );
    }
}
```

The code is far more verbose than what I would write in either C or JavaScript. Is there a less verbose way to accomplish the same outcome in Java? Maybe another class, or a cleaner syntax for initializing structured data?

My team is not Java-savvy, so it is important that the code be easy to read for C/C++ programmers. The kinds of code changes that are most likely are adding and changing the BusConfig objects.

In JavaScript same code looks like this:

```
const IS_EXTENDED = true;

let basicConfig = [
    { bus: 0, gpio: -1, devices: [ "0xa6" ] },
    { bus: 1, gpio: 35, devices: [ "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4" ] },
    { bus: 3, gpio: 38, devices: [ "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4" ] },
];

let extendConfig = [
    { bus: 8, gpio: -1, devices: [ "0xe8" ] },
];

let extendBus0Device = [ "0xa8" ];

if( IS_EXTENDED ) {
    basicConfig = basicConfig.concat( extendConfig );
    basicConfig[0].devices = basicConfig[0].devices.concat( extendBus0Device );
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(basicConfig,null,4) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializing variables that are set in the constructor is unnecessary. Working with the abstract `List` type instead of concrete `ArrayList` allows you to take full advantage of `Arrays.asList` without having to convert the result into an `ArrayList` every time. I personally dislike forcing constructor parameters to have different names than the fields they are assigned to. The `this.` reference is intended for making a distinction between the scope and I find it distracting when I have to read the code to figure out what parameter goes into which field.

```
public final List<String> devices;
public BusConfig(int bus, int gpio, String ... devices) {
    this.bus = bus;
    this.gpio = gpio;
    this.devices = Arrays.asList(devices);
}
```

And then...

```
List<BusConfig> basicConfig = Arrays.asList(
    new BusConfig(0, -1, "0xa6")),
    new BusConfig(1, 35, "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4")),
    new BusConfig(2, 38, "0x80", "0xae", "0xe4"))
);
```

Whether that is easier to understand is subjective, but at least it is shorter and does not have too many unnecessary statements cluttering the code.

There are a few things that I would advise against; all fields being public and the `devices`-list being exposed and manipulated from outside of the `BusConfig`-class.

**Addendum**: *I should have read the JavaDoc...* I did look into the code and confirmed that `Arrays.asList(...)` does return an ArrayList, but with closer inspection, I found out it's not the java.util.ArrayList but an specialized internal ArrayList that is completely different! There doesn't seem to be a common utility library like Apache Commons or Google Commons that would have such a utility, which makes me think that there is a reason for that. If you know why, please add a comment. Anyway, you need to write your own:

```
public class ArrayListUtils {
    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> asArrayList(T... elements) {
        final ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>(elements.length);
        for (T e: elements) {
            list.add(e);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and...

```
import static com.example.ArrayListUtils.toArrayList;
```

and instead of `Arrays.asList(devices)` just call

```
asArrayList(devices)
```

Comment: I'm not sure asList() totally fits the brief, as the list from Arrays.asList() is fixed size and the OP may wish to add entries to their list.

Comment: To avoid the asList issue, devices can be initialized at declaration and then the constructor can use `this.devices.addAll(Arrays.asList(devices));`

Comment: This answer is a major improvement to my code. One important factor, as pointed out by @MarkBluemel, is that the lists need to be modifiable. I was able to make the lists mutable by modifying the initializations from `Arrays.asList(...)` to `new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList(...) )`. If you update the answer to include this -- or a better solution if you know one -- I will accept.

Comment: @MarkBluemel You're absolutely right! I just looked into the code without reading the doc (oops) and checked that it returns an ArrayList... But it's an internal specialized ArrayList, not the one I was thinking about. That class needs a code review. :D

Comment: @LeeJenkins If you find yourself repeating some boilerplate code over and over again and you can't figure out any better way of doing it, it's a good idea to turn it into a utility method. Answer updated and I still can't believe we have to do code like this ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already familiar with JavaScript (which I loathe) and JSON (which I actually like), you may find it helpful to use one of the myriad Java/JSON tools to allow you to represent much of what you want to do in the most natural form.

There are lists of JSON-support packages for various language, including a long list of Java options, at [JSON.ORG](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Below I've implemented the most basic parts of your original example, using [org.json](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) - chosen simply because I have experience of it.

Other tools such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) allow more automatic mapping from JSON notation to objects, but I've only used Jackson in the context of an app server, so would need more time to see how it could be applied here.

If you have much work to do in Java which would be naturally expressed in JSON, then you probably should take the time to see if (say) Jackson would be helpful. (Update: I've found a few minutes to make a first stab at using Jackson - that example is under the org.json version).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

class BusConfig extends Object {

  public int bus;
  public int gpio;
  public ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

  public BusConfig(JSONObject config) {
    bus = config.getInt("bus");
    gpio = config.getInt("gpio");
    for (Object device : config.getJSONArray("devices")) {
      devices.add((String) device);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("{ bus %d, gpio %d, devices %s }", bus, gpio, devices.toString());
  }
}

class ConfigData {

  static final String basicConfigString = "[" //
                                          + "{ bus: 0, gpio: -1, devices: [\"0xa6\" ] },"//
                                          + "{ bus: 1, gpio: 35, devices: [\"0x80\", \"0xae\", \"0xe4\" ] }," //
                                          + "{ bus: 3, gpio: 38, devices: [ \"0x80\", \"0xae\", \"0xe4\" ] }," //
                                          + "]";

  static final JSONArray basicConfigArray = new JSONArray(basicConfigString);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<BusConfig> basicConfig = new ArrayList<BusConfig>();
    for (Object config : basicConfigArray) {
      basicConfig.add(new BusConfig((JSONObject) config));
    }

    System.out.println(basicConfig);
  }
}
```

The Jackson-based example is below. Note that Jackson is, by default, prescriptive about JSON format.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class BusConfig extends Object {

  private int bus;
  private int gpio;
  private List<String> devices;

  public BusConfig() {}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("{ bus %d, gpio %d, devices %s }", getBus(), getGpio(), getDevices().toString());
  }

  public int getBus() {
    return bus;
  }

  public void setBus(int bus) {
    this.bus = bus;
  }

  public int getGpio() {
    return gpio;
  }

  public void setGpio(int gpio) {
    this.gpio = gpio;
  }

  public List<String> getDevices() {
    return devices;
  }

  public void setDevices(List<String> devices) {
    this.devices = devices;
  }
}

class ConfigData {

  static final String basicConfigString = "[" //
                                          + "{ \"bus\": 0, \"gpio\": -1, \"devices\": [\"0xa6\" ] },"//
                                          + "{ \"bus\": 1, \"gpio\": 35, \"devices\": [\"0x80\", \"0xae\", \"0xe4\" ] }," //
                                          + "{ \"bus\": 3, \"gpio\": 38, \"devices\": [ \"0x80\", \"0xae\", \"0xe4\" ] }" //
                                          + "]";

  static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    List<BusConfig> basicConfig = objectMapper.readValue(basicConfigString, new TypeReference<List<BusConfig>>() {});
    System.out.println(basicConfig);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that nobody had said about import statements. Using .* is not good practice specially if you using just 2 classes from that pacage. So it should be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Posibly I am blind, but which class from java.util.regex pacage is used? Also no need to extend Object, as Object is the base class of all Java classes. In toString() you don´t need to use this, but you could get a NullPointerException if devices is null.

This code:

```
if( IS_EXTENDED ) {
            basicConfig.get(0).devices.addAll(extendBus0Device);
            basicConfig.addAll(extendConfig);
        }
```

makes no sence, since IS_EXTENDED is false. In JavaScript version it´s true which makes the if statement useless.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend a bit on the review by @TorbenPutkonen and the comments that followed:

Are you sure you need the list need to be mutable? The is a bit of a trend in programming languages and patterns towards immutable data structures. You have only shown a basic modification of what you are doing with your data structures, but nothing in that suggests you couldn't use immutables, especially depending on the Java version you are using (or by using some libraries).

Java 9 introduced the [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) static method to create simple immutable Lists.

```
List<BusConfig> basicConfig = List.of(
    new BusConfig(...)),
    new BusConfig(...)),
    new BusConfig(...))
);
```

Then Java 14 introduced [`record`s](https://www.baeldung.com/java-record-keyword) which are a way to create immutable classes:

```
public record BusConfig(int bus, int gpio, List<String> devices) {}
```

Resulting in:

```
List<BusConfig> basicConfig = List.of(
    new BusConfig(0, -1, List.of("0xa6"))),
    new BusConfig(1, 35, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4"))),
    new BusConfig(2, 38, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4")))
);
```

Now we need a way to modify/append the list of devices. Unfortunately the stand Java API misses a simple method to concatenate (immutable) lists, but here is an example utility method to do it:

```
static public <E> List<E> concat(List<E> lists...) {
    return Arrays.stream(lists).flatMap(list -> list.stream()).toList();
}
```

(The final `.toList()` requires Java 16. It can be replaced with `.collect(Collectors.toList());` in earlier versions.)

With that we can define a "with-er" method that creates a copy of the  `record` *with* a new device `List`:

```
public record BusConfig(int bus, int gpio, List<String> devices) {
    public BusConfig withDevices(List<String> newDevices) {
        return new BusConfig(bus, gpio, newDevices);
    }
}
```

Finally we need a way to replace an item in an immutable list, which again is lacking in teh standard Java API:

```
static public <E> List<E> replace(List<E> list, int index, E item) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size()).map(i -> i == index ? item : list.get(i)).toList();
}
```

So the main part of your script becomes:

```
List<BusConfig> basicConfig = List.of(
    new BusConfig(0, -1, List.of("0xa6"))),
    new BusConfig(1, 35, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4"))),
    new BusConfig(2, 38, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4")))
);

List<BusConfig> extendConfig = List.of(
    new BusConfig(8, -1, List.of("0xe8"))
);
List<String> extendBus0Device = List.of("0xa8");

List<BusConfig> newConfig;
if (IS_EXTENDED) {
    BusConfig first = basicConfig.get(0);
    BusConfig newFirst = first.withDevices(concat(first.devices(), extendBus0Device));
    newConfig = concat(replace(basicConfig, 0, newFirst), extendConfig);
} else {
    newConfig = basicConfig;
}

System.out.println(newConfig);
```

I admit this requires a quite a bit of boilerplate and utility methods, but I  believe in the long run it's more concise yet still readable.

If you can't use the newer Java versions, or if you want to avoid the boilerplate and utility methods, there are many libraries around that can help out.

For example, instead of `record` the library [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) has the annotation `@Value` which creates classes with similar features as `record`s plus can generate the "with-er" methods automatically.

And [`vavr`](https://www.vavr.io/) provides an alternative implementation of an immutable list. Together you can then have your whole script look like this:

```
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.With;
import io.vavr.collection.List;

@Value 
@With
class BusConfig() {
    int bus;
    int gpio;
    List<String> devices;
}

class ConfigData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean IS_EXTENDED = false;
        List<BusConfig> basicConfig = List.of(
            new BusConfig( 0, -1, List.of("0xa6") ),
            new BusConfig( 1, 35, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4") ),
            new BusConfig( 2, 38, List.of("0x80", "0xae", "0xe4") )
        );
        List<BusConfig> extendConfig = List.of(
            new BusConfig( 8, -1, List.of("0xe8")
        );

        List<String> extendBus0Device = List.of("0xa8");

        List<BusConfig> newConfig = IS_EXTENDED 
            ? basicConfig.update(0, first => first.withDevices(first.getDevices().appendAll(extendBus0Device)).appendAll(extendConfig)
            : basicConfig;

         System.out.println( newConfig );
     }
 }
```

(I used `vavr`s `List` here, which internally is a linked list, but there is also `Array` which uses an Java array.)